# Delete a folder in github, but not in local

Tags: git, github

I know that if I want to ignore folder that I don't want to push to Github. I could use `.gitignore` to ignore it.

Now my situation is I had pushed the folder up to Github, now I wish I could ignore it and delete it on Github, but still want the folder in local side.

How could I achieve it?

Comment: + 1 to JB's solution below. If that does not work, create a branch locally (with the folder) and do the steps without `--rm`. This will delete the folder locally+remote. Then bring the folder back from the branch.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It seems like the `--cached` option of [git rm](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rm.html) is what you want.

```
git rm --cached fileToDelete
git commit master
git push origin master
Now add the file to .gitignore
```

Not tested though.

Comment: yes!!!!this is what I need

`git rm --cached -r fileToDelete` works for me :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In order for you to remove the **folder or file** from **Github** but no from you **computer** use this command in the following order

1. **git rm -r --cached** `name-of-the-folder`
2. **git commit -m** `"insert your comment inside this quotation marks"`
3. **git push origin**

in case you have several `branches` you can do

- **git push origin** `master`
- **git push origin** `branchName`

---

**EXAMPLE**

1. `git rm -r --cached .vscode`
2. `git commit -m "removed the .vscode folder"`
3. `git push origin`